# Using an ARSCNPlaneGeometry to obtain a SCNPhysicsShape produces a sphere shape and not a plane

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, arscnview

In an application using `ARKit`, I am using the `ARSCNPlaneGeometry` class `update` method to obtain a `SCNGeometry` from an `ARPlaneGeometry`. I obtain a `SCNPhysicsShape` from that geometry to use as the `SCNPhysicsBody` for a plane node:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    // Plane Geometry
    let planeGeometry = ARSCNPlaneGeometry(device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
    planeGeometry?.update(from: planeAnchor.geometry)
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)

    // Plane Physics
    planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: planeGeometry!))

    // Add Node to Scene
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}
```

The problem I have is that even though the plane node displayed is a plane, the physics shape that is generated is not that of a plane but that of a rough sphere. I know this because I am using the scene view debug option `.showPhysicsShapes`.

I am also continuously updating the geometry and physics shape using the `renderer(_:didUpdate:for:)` method of the `ARSCNViewDelegate` and the shape remains the same.

Anybody else run into this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the shape abstraction that the SCNPhysicsShape class calculates from an ARSCNPlaneGeometry is completely off unless you help it a little bit with an option. If instead of:

```
planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: planeGeometry!))
```

you use:

```
planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: planeGeometry!, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.boundingBox]))
```

The "approximate", although not quite exact, shape is obtained.